# Print reverse of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried running the following code. I tried returning value of j also but it just doesn't work.

```
def reverse(n):  

   j=0  

while(n!=0):  

        j=j*10  

        j=j + (n%10)  

        n=n/10  

print(j)  

reverse(45)
```

Comment: In Python 3, use `//` for integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a program to reverse a number

```
def reverse(n):
    v = []
    for item in reversed(list(str(n))):
        v.append(item)
    return ''.join(v)

print(reverse("45"))
```

returns

```
54
```

The reverse() function creates an array, adds each digit from the input to said array, and then prints it as plain text. If you want the data from that as an integer then you can replace the return command to this at the end of the function

```
return int(''.join(v))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you made one mistake only: for Python 3 you need to use an integer division: n = n // 10.
Here is the correct code without str and list:

```
def reverse(n):
    j = 0
    while n != 0:
        j = j * 10
        j = j + (n%10)
        n = n // 10
    print(j)
reverse(12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code for Python 3:

```
import sys

def reverse(x):
    while x>0:
         sys.stdout.write(str(x%10))
         x = x//10   # x = x/10 (Python 2)
    print()   # print (Python 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 45
int(str(number)[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1234
a = int("".join(reversed(str(a))))
print a
```

This will give a = 4321

reversed functions returns an iterable object. If we do :

```
a = list(reversed(str(a)))
```

it will return [“3”,”2″,”1″]. We have then joined it and converted into int.